# Find row-sets with mismatched values without large self join?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a table like this (basic example, not the real thing):

```
FKEY  | NAME  | ATTRIBUTE_X
--------------------------
 1      '...'    42
 1      '...'    42
 1      '...'    42
 2      '...'    7
 2      '...'    7
 5      '...'    42
 5      '...'    42
 5      '...'    42
 5      '...'    42
 6      '...'    300
 6      '...'    300
 ....
```

Where - normally - each of the attribute_x values for a given fkey are all the same. (In my real data, I calculate attribute_x from some columns in the table and this property needs to be the same for all rows with the same fkey.

Now I have some rows where this property does not hold. I want to search the whole table to find all FKEYs with mismatched attribute_x values.

Example:

```
--------------------------
 145678973      '...'    23
 145678973      '...'    22 // Error, should also be 23
 145678973      '...'    23
```

My naive approach was:

```
SELECT distinct(TX1.FKEY)
FROM TABLEX TX1, TABLEX TX2
WHERE TX1.FKEY=TX2.FKEY
  AND TX1.ATTRIBUTE_X <> TX2.ATTRIBUTE_X
;
```

But with my real data this doesn't complete (I ran of of temp tablespace and after the DBA increased the temp tablespace to 20 GIG the query ran for a few hours and then bailed out.)

Generally, is there a more efficient query for this?

---

I have a solution with PL/SQL where I just loop over the table sorted by FKEY, and if I find a different attribute_x vs. the last fetched record where the fkey stayed the same, I have found an erroneous fkey.

But this seems oh so primitve :-) Is there an efficient pure SQL solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
select fkey
from tablex
group by fkey
having count(distinct attribute_x) > 1
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer instead of [Helena's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8260067/321013) because this version would also work for a non numerical `attribute_x`.

Comment: Note: This version and the one with MAX <> MIN have exactly the same cost for the auto-traces of my real data: `17518` :-)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

```
select
  FKEY
from
  (
  select distinct
    FKEY,
    ATTRIBUTE_X
  from
    MYTABLE
  )
group by
  FKEY
having
  count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, corrected. The solution from @Mark Bannister is better though. Using count distinct is much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Also the following should work:

`SELECT fkey FROM mytable GROUP BY fkey HAVING MIN(attribute_x) <> MAX(attribute_x)`

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
select count(*),FKEY from (Select distinct FKEY,ATTRIBUTE_X from TABLEX) 
having count(*)>1
```

**EDIT** I corrected the query there was 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE (fkey, name, attribute_x) NOT IN
  (SELECT fkey, name, attribute_x FROM tablex
   GROUP BY fkey)
```

or (if name has not to be taken in account)

```
SELECT * FROM tablex
WHERE (fkey, attribute_x) NOT IN
  (SELECT fkey, attribute_x FROM tablex
   GROUP BY fkey)
```

Comment: Won't this return the entire table? Plus wouldn't it be still considered a self-join (albeit semi-self-join :) ?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: no, my query (I tested it) return only records with different attributes for every fkey.

Comment: @MarkBannister: no, my query (I tested it) returns records having attribute_x column different from the first one for every fkey :)

Comment: These queries will take a **long** time with the OP's dataset.

Comment: @MarkBannister: ok, this comment is well accepted and correct!! :) Yes, this is not the best solution, but I don't want to copy other solutions that have already have been posted! :) Thanks Mark

Comment: @Marco: Oh I get it now =), this synthax wouldn't work in Oracle though, since you can't have a column in the SELECT clause if it is not either in the GROUP BY clause or part of an aggregate. It would work with MIN() or MAX() I think.